# Animate view layer transition

Tags: animation, viewlayers, compositing-nodes

I'm trying to achieve an effect where I have one object in different styles (colourful, wireframe, voxelized) and I'm trying to animate fading between them in a scene with a moving camera. I've come up with several options but they all feel clunky for what seems like a simple problem

Options I've tried:

- Animate the alpha of the materials in eevee. This works great however some objects have multiple materials that would all need to be keyframed to fade together.
- Put one object per view layer. Then composite them back together using the compositor achieving the fade effect by keyframing the mix node factor. This shows a lot of promise however experimenting with the timing is very slow because I can only see the entire effect once I render the animation - there is on option to preview it like in the view port (I have to press the render button on the render layers input node).

This feels like a very standard problem so I wonder if there is an obvious solution I'm missing (animating opacity at the object level). Or perhaps there is a workflow I'm not aware of with the compositor?

Comment: "*Put one object per view layer. Then composite them back together using the compositor*" This would be the standard procedure, scrubbing the time line should suffice to update previews. Note that you should first render the whole animation as image sequence then composite from static files in a separate .blend specifically for this purpose. Alternatively if it is just simple fading, use the VSE instead

Comment: +1 to Duarte ... just a note to your first solution - you can create a node group with keyframed  alpha and place this group as part of each material ... like that you can control transition from one place for all materials

Comment: I ended up setting up drivers to control all the material alphas together. I'll look into the node group solution

Comment: Great you found solution ... Don't hesitate to fully answer your question here so others can learn from you. Thank you